# Search symbol form the math equation in java

Tags: java, math

Is there java API or solution to retrieve the symbols from the mathematics equation in Java?

Eg. Equation

```
y = (x1 + x2) / (a + b)
x = (-b±√(b^2-4ac))/(2a)
x = sin(a) * 0.56
```

My expected program is

```
Equation e1 = new Equation("y = (x1 + x2) / (a + b)");
List<String> symbolList = SymbolFinder.search(e1);
for(String sb : symbolList ) {
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

Output :

```
y
x1
x2
a
b
```

Comment: try to use more broad approach. Finding substrings in pred-defined format inside the string. Well, regular expressions might help.

Comment: define your grammar and use antlr, have a look at simple example of calculator in antlr

Answer (score 1):

Try [JFormula](http://www.japisoft.com/formula/doc/). And take a look at [this method](http://www.japisoft.com/formula/javadoc/com/japisoft/formula/Formula.html#getSymbolNames%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

This *sort-of* does the trick:

```
String eq = "y = (x1 + x2) / (a + b)";      
String[] s = eq.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
```

The array will contain the symbols x1, x2, a, b and y, but also some whitespace too.
It is also unable to spot whether one symbol consists of 2 letters or if they are separate symbols.

Comment: Well if you have per example `String eq = "y = (x1^2 + x2) / (a + b)";   `, your solution doesn't work.

Comment: there might be scientific equations like `sin(a) *( b / c)`. It is not ok.

Comment: Good points. It would return sin as a symbol, but it's a function. Any solution would need to know about any function it may come across. Also, the trick is to decide what is a symbol. In the first example, x1 and x2 are symbols OK, but in the Polynomail Equation example, `4ac` would be returned as a symbol too. It is possible to make it clever enough to exclude the 4, but `ac` - is that 2 symbols or 1? I know it's 2 because I know the equation, but I can't define an algorithm for deciding that.